# How to extract the data from encoded HTML class using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How can I retrieve the page encoded div class  of a  webpage (title **html** tag) using **Python**?

Here my sample html code.

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Have you considered using the xml module in python ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html 

It would allows you to explore the DOM tree and query the nodes contents and attributes.

Comment: Please, never place an image on StackOverflow if it's an HTML or some sort of a code snippet. Because of this, your question may immediately end up in the "trash". Sorry to be rude, but it's true. You can use [image to text](https://brandfolder.com/workbench/extract-text-from-image) tool to make it an HTML snippet so people could faster answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#quickstart) to make a request (it will automatically decode the page, *in most cases*), and [`beautifulsoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to extract the data from the HTML.

---

**Update** after [OP clarifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70121830/how-to-extract-the-data-from-encoded-html-class-using-python#comment124007040_70122133). `CSS` classes are not dynamically updating, they're the same (*that's what I noticed*). Since they're the same, you can:

- grab a container with all needed data (a container (CSS selector) that wraps needed data)

```py
for result in soup.select(".pSzOP-AhqUyc-qWD73c.GNzUNc span"):
    # ...
```

- use `regex` to filter (find) *all* needed data via [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and capture group `(.*)`: only this match will be captured and returned. `.*`: means to capture everything.

```py
if re.findall(r"^Telephone\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text):
   # ...
```

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. On that note, there's a dedicated [web scraping with CSS selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/) blog post of mine.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/How-to-extract-the-data-from-encoded-HTML-class-using-python#main.py):

```py
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://sites.google.com/a/arden.solihull.sch.uk/futures/home")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser")

# all regular expressions for this task
# https://regex101.com/r/cxdxgq/1

for result in soup.select(".pSzOP-AhqUyc-qWD73c.GNzUNc span"):
    
    if re.findall(r"^Careers\s?.*\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text):
        name = "".join(re.findall(r"^Careers\s?.*\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text.strip()))
        print(name)

    if re.findall(r"^Telephone\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text):
        telephone = "".join(re.findall(r"^Telephone\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text.strip()))
        print(telephone)

    if re.findall(r"^Email\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text):
        email = "".join(re.findall(r"^Email\s?:\s?(.*)", result.text.strip()))
        print(email)

# to scrape the role you can do the same thing with regex. Test on regex101.com

'''
Mrs A. Fallis
01564 773348
afallis@arden.solihull.sch.uk
Mr S. Brady
01564 7733478
sbrady@arden.solihull.sch.uk
'''
```

---

First solutions without OP clarifications (shows only extraction part since you haven't provided a website URL):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="L581yb VICjCf" hjdwnd-ahquyc-r6poud="" jndksc="" l6ctce-pszop"="" l6ctce-purzt="" tabindex=" == $0
&lt;div class=">
</div>
<div class="hJDwNd-AhqUyc-WNfPc purZT-AhqUyC-I15mzb PSzOP-AhqUyc-qWD73c JNdks &lt;div class=" jndksc-smkayb"="">
 <div class="" f570id"="" jsaction="zXBUYD: ZTPCnb; 2QF9Uc: Qxe3nd;
jsname=" jscontroller="SGWD4d">
  &gt;
  <div class="oKdM2C KzvoMe">
   <div class="hJDwNd-AhqUyc-WNFPC PSzOP-AhqUyc- qWD73c jXK9ad D2fZ2 Oj CsFc whaque GNzUNC" id="h.7f5e93de0cf8a767_49">
    <div class="]XK9ad-SmkAyb">
     <div class="ty]Ctd mGzaTb baZpAe">
      <div class="GV3q8e aP9Z7e" id="h.p_9livxd801krd">
      </div>
      <h3 class="CDt4ke zfr3Q OmQG5e" dir="ltr" id="h.p_9livxd801krd" tabindex="-1">
       .
      </h3>
      <div class="GV3q8e aP9z7e" id="h.p JrEgQYpyORCF">
      </div>
      <h3 class="CDt 4Ke zfr3Q OmQG5e" dir="ltr" id="h.p_JrEgQYPYORCF" tabindex="-1">
       <div class="CjVfdc" jsaction="touchstart:UrsOsc; click:Kjs
qPd; focusout:QZoaz; mouseover:yOpDld; mouseout:dq0hvd;fvlRjc:jbFSO
d;CrflRd:SzACGe;" jscontroller="Ae65rd">
        <div class="PPHIP rviiZ" jsname="haAclf">
         .
        </div>
        <span style="font-family: 'Oswald'; font-weight: 500;">
         Telephone : 01564 773348
        </span>
       </div>
      </h3>
      <div class="GV3q8e aP9z7e" id="h.p_sylefz-BOSBX">
      </div>
      &gt;&lt;h3 id="h.p_sylefz-BOSBX" dir="ltr" class="CDt 4Ke zfr3Q OmQG5e"
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
"""

# pass HTML to BeautifulSoup object and assign a html.parser as a HTML parser
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# grab a phone number (only first occurrence will be extracted)
# https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors
print(soup.select_one('.CjVfdc span').text.strip())

# Telephone : 01564 773348


# extract <div> element with .L581yb class. returns a list()
print(soup.select('.L581yb'))

'''
[<div class="L581yb VICjCf" hjdwnd-ahquyc-r6poud="" jndksc="" l6ctce-pszop"="" l6ctce-purzt="" tabindex=" == $0
&lt;div class=">
</div>]
'''


# extract <div> element with .hJDwNd-AhqUyc-WNfPc class. returns a list()
print(soup.select('.hJDwNd-AhqUyc-WNfPc'))

'''
[<div class="hJDwNd-AhqUyc-WNfPc purZT-AhqUyC-I15mzb PSzOP-AhqUyc-qWD73c JNdks &lt;div class=" jndksc-smkayb"="">
<div class="" f570id"="" jsaction="zXBUYD: ZTPCnb; 2QF9Uc: Qxe3nd;
jsname=" jscontroller="SGWD4d">
  &gt;
  <div class="oKdM2C KzvoMe">
<div class="hJDwNd-AhqUyc-WNFPC PSzOP-AhqUyc- qWD73c jXK9ad D2fZ2 Oj CsFc whaque GNzUNC" id="h.7f5e93de0cf8a767_49">
<div class="]XK9ad-SmkAyb">
<div class="ty]Ctd mGzaTb baZpAe">
<div class="GV3q8e aP9Z7e" id="h.p_9livxd801krd">
</div>
<h3 class="CDt4ke zfr3Q OmQG5e" dir="ltr" id="h.p_9livxd801krd" tabindex="-1">
       .
      </h3>
<div class="GV3q8e aP9z7e" id="h.p JrEgQYpyORCF">
</div>
<h3 class="CDt 4Ke zfr3Q OmQG5e" dir="ltr" id="h.p_JrEgQYPYORCF" tabindex="-1">
<div class="CjVfdc" jsaction="touchstart:UrsOsc; click:Kjs
qPd; focusout:QZoaz; mouseover:yOpDld; mouseout:dq0hvd;fvlRjc:jbFSO
d;CrflRd:SzACGe;" jscontroller="Ae65rd">
<div class="PPHIP rviiZ" jsname="haAclf">
         .
        </div>
<span style="font-family: 'Oswald'; font-weight: 500;">
         Telephone : 01564 773348
        </span>
</div>
</h3>
<div class="GV3q8e aP9z7e" id="h.p_sylefz-BOSBX">
</div>
      &gt;&lt;h3 id="h.p_sylefz-BOSBX" dir="ltr" class="CDt 4Ke zfr3Q OmQG5e"
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>]
'''
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitry, But encoded class names  are dynamically  changing

Comment: @suresh could you provide a website URL? Without it, there is little I (someone else) can do to help.

Comment: sure, Dimitry, I am trying to extract the First Name
Last Name
Email Address
Link at where the contact info was found

Comment: this the website, https://sites.google.com/a/arden.solihull.sch.uk/futures/home

Comment: @suresh Have a look at the updated solution I edited. If this answers your question, would appreciate if you mark it as correct.